# Parse iOS hide statusbar on PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse's standard user login view controller.  The problem is when it appears it shows the iOS status bar at the top of the screen.  I've tried disabling the status bar in the plist and in my storyboard but whenever the PFLogInViewController appears the status bar appears.

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];


        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Create the sign up view controller
        PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
        [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

        // Present the log in view controller

        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PFLogInViewController.swift

add the following code:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

If you don't have access to this file, create an extension. Create a new swift file, name it as you wish. then paste the following code inside it:

```
import Foundation

extension PFLogInViewController {
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

For Object-C, the approach is pretty the same. 
Add this code to PFLogInViewController.m

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}
```

and if you don't have an access to this file. create a category. Select File -> New File -> Objective C File, Choose File Type as Category. Give it a name, and class should be PFLogInViewController Then inside the .m file add the method of preferred status bar hidden to return YES.

Comment: This was an Objective-C question.